# Subequation: Counter too large and alphalph does not work

Tags: packages, counters, subequations

I have an urgent question. I am writing a document and I have equations (but they are more than 26). I get the error 'counter too large'. I saw in other topics that I need to use `alphalph` package but it does not work and I still get the same error. I would be so grateful if you help me solve this. I have copied and pasted a minimal example of my code and all packages which I am using:

```
\documentclass {article} 
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag,balance,arydshln}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mempatch}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{cleveref}   
\usepackage{xr}     
\usepackage{nomencl}  
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}    
\usepackage{bbold}  
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}     
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{nameref}    
\usepackage{dsfont}     
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{xcolor}     
\usepackage{alphalph,etoolbox}
    \allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\begin{subequations}
\label{equation1}
\begin{align}
& a=b+c \\ 
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: off-topic: for reproduce your problem is sufficient the following preamble: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph,mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document} ...`

Comment: Needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`, `epsfig` is obsolete (`graphicx` does the job) and `enumerate` is incompatible with `enumitem`.

Comment: Are you sure about T5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little bit messed up. Several packages are repeated...

Anyways just very fastly i tried to fix with alphalph and etoolbox.

Try this:

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}%%%lemme convince you to use utf8 here...
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}


\usepackage{amsthm, latexsym, amsfonts,amssymb, psfrag,balance,arydshln, bbold, pgfplots, epstopdf, dsfont}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, mempatch, ifdraft, color, enumitem, verbatim, gensymb, enumerate, epsfig, hhline}
\usepackage{textcomp, acronym, cleveref, xr, nomencl, url, paralist, bm, glossaries, algorithmic, pgfplots}
\usepackage{bibentry, nameref, booktabs, cite, multirow, framed, lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption, capt-of, makecell, appendix, pgfplotstable, mathtools, xcolor, alphalph,etoolbox}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}

 %%    
 %% I don't remember from where i got this
 %% probably from Werner user
 %%
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\alphalphval}[1]{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{%
    \let\alph\alphalphval%
  }
}
   %%
   %% Probable Werner's code.
   %% Who knows please provide link here.
   %%

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}


\begin{subequations}\label{equation1}
\begin{align}
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: U welcome! not my solution though. I had that code in one of my .tex files but i forgot who told me how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Merely *loading* the `alphalph` package isn't enough. You also need to provide the following instruction after `\begin{subequations}` and before `\begin{align}`:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation \alphalph{\value{equation}}}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc} % why not 'utf8'?
\usepackage{alphalph}   

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\label{equation1}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation\alphalph{\value{equation}}}
\begin{align}
& a=b+c \\ 
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c \\
& a=b+c 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```